# How find error authentication passport and react?

Tags: reactjs, axios, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I have also error with passportjs. Before errors if you know good tutorial passportjs, passport-local-mongoose with react please send me link.

I watch a video youtube and work code in [that][1] . This is github. But I want change authentication passport. In modaljs I do this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const moment = require("moment");
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        maxlength:50
    },
    email: {
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        unique: 1 
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        minglength: 5
    },
    lastname: {
        type:String,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    role : {
        type:Number,
        default: 0 
    },
    image: String
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'});

const User = mongoose.model( 'User' , userSchema );

module.exports = {User};
```

in Userjs I do this:

```
const { User } = require('../models/model');
const router = require('express').Router();
const passport = require('passport');

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser( async function(id, done) {
    await User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

router.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    // res.send(req.isAuthenticated)
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.status(200).json({
            _id: req.user._id,
            isAdmin: req.user.role === 0 ? false : true,
            isAuth: true,
            email: req.user.email,
            name: req.user.name,
            lastname: req.user.lastname,
            role: req.user.role,
            image: req.user.image,
        });
    }
    else{
        return res.json({
            isAuth: false,
            error: true
        });
    }
});
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    await User.register( {email: req.body.email}, req.body.password, (err,user)=>{
        if(err) return res.json({ success: false, err });    
        else res.status(200).json({
            success: true
        });
    });
});

router.post("/login", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
      console.log("ok!");
        res.json({
        loginSuccess: false,
            message: "Invalid email or password"
        });
        
    });

});


router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated){
        req.logout();
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true
        });
    }
    else return res.json({success: false});
});

module.exports = router;
```

in server.js I add passport and this:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

When first time I start server I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

But after I get nothink. only show console req.body. How find error. I am very tired with passportjs. Where I find best tutorial passportjs with plugin database in passport-local-mongoose. And How find error  and fix it. Sorry my english:))
[1]: https://github.com/jaewonhimnae/boilerplate-mern-stack

Comment: Your `passport.authenticate` call doesn't look right. http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122908/how-find-some-error-send-data-react-to-backend/67123374#67123374

Comment: last time I have like error. but this time I think have some little errors with axios or redux ... please see:)

Answer (score 0):

Please try res.status(200).send instead of res.status(200).json

Comment: Its cannot help. But when I send data backend using postman all work good. but send data frontend cannot work. Why I dont know. please see _actions and login page. help me